# Maximum Occurrence in Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with counting maximum sequential occurrence of event, which have `flag=1`, for each `human`.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE max_in_row
(
    [date_var] varchar(13), 
    [human] varchar(57), 
    [flag] int
);

INSERT INTO max_in_row ([date_var], [human], [flag])
VALUES
    ('2020-03-08', 'Dmitrii', 0),
    ('2020-03-09', 'Dmitrii', 1),
    ('2020-03-30', 'Dmitrii', 0),
    ('2020-03-12', 'Alex', 1),
    ('2020-03-11', 'Dmitrii', 0),
    ('2020-03-13', 'Dmitrii', 0),
    ('2020-03-14', 'Alex', 1),
    ('2020-03-10', 'Dmitrii', 1),
    ('2020-04-01', 'Dmitrii', 1),
    ('2020-04-02', 'Dmitrii', 0),
    ('2020-03-11', 'Alex', 0),
    ('2020-04-01', 'Alex', 1),
    ('2020-04-02', 'Alex', 1),
    ('2020-04-03', 'Alex', 0),
    ('2020-03-12', 'Alex', 1);
```

And assume to obtain:

```
Alex    : 3
Dmitrii : 2
```

I tried to use `row_number() over partition` function, but not sure why it doesn't work for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the logic to get the results you are after? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Also, why is your column `date_var` a `varchar` when it's clearly storing a date; why is it not a `date`?

Comment: `counting maximum sequantal occurrence of event, which have flag=1` your example of result is more like count of all occurences where flag =1 for each human... I don't understand where is `sequantal occurrence`

Comment: @Larnu I what to sort the table by `date_var` and count what is maximum sequence with `flag=1` events

Comment: @demo I will add more rows to the example

Comment: @VemenBusat, now I get it... sort by date :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you have is a gaps and islands problem. One method, therefore, would be the below to firstly put the rows into groups, then count the rows in said groups, and finally return the maximum values:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
    SELECT date_var,
           human,
           flag,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_var) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY human, flag ORDER BY date_var) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.max_in_row),
Counts AS(
    SELECT human,
           COUNT(date_var) AS InSequence
    FROM Grps
    WHERE flag = 1
    GROUP BY human,
             Grp)
SELECT human,
       MAX(InSequence) AS MaxSequence
FROM Counts
GROUP BY human;
```